# How to - Java Thread Accessing Other Thread (SWING)

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

Regarding the problem,

when i start a thread from the main application, lets say process A runs in background and updates a text box outside of the thread saying it's running and completed when it has stop running.

How do i write the code which updates the textbox outside the thread from within the running thread ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need a pointer to the text box.
the thread **cannot** update the text box - in swing, all GUI commands must be executed from the event dispatch thread.

you must do:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater ( new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        // draw textbox code
    }
});
```

this will add the object to the queue executed by the event dispatch thread

EDIT:
just a tip:
inside the new Runnable(){ ... }, which is an anonymous class, you won't be able to use a regular variable from the outside scope. You must define a variable as final, or use a getter to fetch the textbox (or address it through some static field).

Comment: how do i invoke the textbox properties which has already been drawn on the form?

Comment: Oh. thanks for the tip. i created a static reference within the runnable class and bridge the textbox from the gui.
something like : Test.txt  = jTextArea1
and within the run of Test, i just use txt.setText() to set the text and it works.

Comment: It does not need to be static, (anonymous and named) inner classes can access the state of their outer class.

Comment: that's nested classes. anonymous classes require the variables in the wrapping scope to be final.